# Content of ScrollView out of parent's boundaries

Tags: java, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a Layout as shown below in the xml code. Inside the `ScrollView` I want to attach `LinearLayouts` which shall later contain an `ImageView` and a little textline below it. This, I have to do programmatically. While the images load, the `LinearLayout` shall show an indeterminate `ProgressBar`, which is removed before the the image and the text is added. All this is done in `AsyncTasks`.

fragment_images.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity         = "center"
    android:layout_height   = "match_parent"
    android:layout_width    = "match_parent" >


    <ScrollView
        android:id              = "@+id/scrollview_fragment_species_images_vertical"
        android:layout_height   = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_width    = "wrap_content"
        android:orientation     = "vertical" 
        android:visibility      = "gone" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity  = "center"
            android:id              = "@+id/linlay_fragment_species_images_vertical"
            android:layout_height   = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_width    = "wrap_content"
            android:orientation     = "vertical" 
            android:visibility      = "gone" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code, which loads the images, adds and populates the `LinearLayouts`:

```
ScrollView scrollViewVert  = (ScrollView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scrollview_fragment_species_images_vertical);
scrollViewVert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
LinearLayout linlayContainer = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.linlay_fragment_species_images_vertical);
linlayContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

private void makeImageList(String jsonImages) {

    // ...

    for (int i=0; i<count_images; i++) {
        final ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);


        final LinearLayout childContainer = new LinearLayout(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        childContainer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        childContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        childContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        childContainer.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);


        final TextView childText = new TextView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        childText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        childText.setPadding(15, 10, 15, 5);
        String imageSize = (Integer.parseInt(templist.get(i)[2]) / 1024) + "kB";
        childText.setText(imageSize);
        childText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


        final ImageView child = new ImageView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        child.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        child.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 0);


        URL url = null;
        try {url = new URL(address);} // just an internet address. this works!
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        linlayContainer.addView(childContainer);
        childContainer.addView(progress);


        new AsyncTask<URL, Void, Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... params) {
                Bitmap image = null;
                try {image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(params[0].openConnection().getInputStream());}
                catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                return image;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
                child.setImageBitmap(image);
                childContainer.removeView(progress);
                childContainer.addView(child);
                childContainer.addView(childText);
            }
        }.execute(url);
    }
}
```

Somehow my layout is shifted vertically and I don't understand why. The images below show the problem. Left, the upper limit of the `ScrollView` is reached with one image not visible; right is the lower end of the `ScrollView` with too much free space. Maybe it's irrelevant, but this is a tabbed fragment activity. I don't know how I can narrow down the error any further.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Upper limit of ScrollView]
[image: Lower limit of ScrollView]

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, though I don't understand, what exactly is wrong here:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity = "center"
...
```

The `LinearLayout` inside of the `ScrollView` must be centred only horizontally, not horizontally *and* vertically. So, the line above must be corrected as such:

```
        android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"
```

If anyone would be so kind and explain, why the `layout_gravity`-parameter is not limited to the parent view, but apparently to the whole screen or whatever root view it is... I don't understand it.